# SQL Select statement for NOT IN multiple values for groups of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the NOT IN query but apply it to batches of rows where a column value is the same.
`SELECT * FROM CHECKOUTS WHERE ProductId NOT IN (2345)` will return the row where the ProductName is Toy2 and Toy3 but I want it to not return Toy2 b/c the CheckoutId is the same as the Toy1.

Essentially I want the NOT IN query to run in batches of rows that have the same CheckoutId. Instead of returning the Toy2 and Toy3 I want it to return just Toy3.

| CheckoutId | ProductId | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2345 | Toy1 |
| 1234 | 0987 | Toy2 |
| 0123 | 8787 | Toy3 |

Is this even possible? I feel like I need a completely new query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the query in two steps, although they can be combined in one query. First step: find those checkout ids you don't want. Second step: get the checkout records without those ids.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHECKOUTS 
WHERE 
    CheckoutId NOT IN (
        SELECT CheckoutId 
        FROM CHECKOUTS 
        WHERE ProductId IN (2345));
```